# How can I make a JavaScript code that recognizes strings of similar elements?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, variables

I'm currently trying to write a JavaScript program which is able to recognize strings of similar elements. For example, suppose you had the **ordered** variables

```
var x1 = 1;
var x2 = 1;
var x3 = 0;
var x4 = 0;
var x5 = 1;
var x6 = 1;
var x7 = 1;
var x8 = 0;
var x9 = 1;
var x10 = 0;
```

I'm trying to produce a program which could tell you that these ordered variables contain one string of two 1's, one string of three 1's, and one string of one 1.

I thought I might be able to do this using an if statement, maybe something like

```
var i = 1;
var s = 0;

if(x_i == 1) {
    var s = s ++;
    var i = i++
}

elseif(x_i == 0) {
document.getElementById('string-length').innerHTML = s;

}
```

However, it is obviously not correct to write x_i to refer to each variable x1, x2, x3, ...

What should I do to make the program look at each variable in order and then consider the number of consecutive 1's in the list of ordered variables?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is the starting point: You don't want a list of variables with digits in their names. You want an array.

Comment: You should make the variables into an object so it is easier to work with...

Comment: I'm not really sure what an array is. Do you know any good places where I can learn about how to use them?

Comment: Can use an object like a dictionary but (according to specs) object properties aren't ordered. You need an array.

Comment: Is using `window["x" + i]` an option for you to access the variables?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said you're open to using a array. That looks like this:

```
var x = [
    1,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    0,
    1,
    0
];
```

Then you can loop through that array, keeping track of what you see:

```
var found; // Defaults to the value `undefined`
var count = 0;
x.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (found === entry) {
        ++count;
    } else {
        if (count) {
            console.log("Found " + count + " " + found + "s");
        }
        found = entry;
        count = 1;
    }
});
if (count) {
    console.log("Found " + count + " " + found);
}
```

`Array#forEach` calls the function you give it once per entry, passing in the entry. We use that to compare to `found` and if it's a match, we increase `count`. If not (and it won't be the first time), we say what we found before (if anything) and then remember the new thing we've found.

The reason `found` won't be `=== entry` on the first pass is that the default value of a variable is `undefined`, and `undefined` is not `===` either 0 or 1, because `===` is the "strict" equality operator, which means that the operands are only considered equal if they have the same type and value. `undefined` is not a number, so it doesn't have the same type.

**Live Example:**

```js
var x = [
  1,
  1,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  1,
  1,
  0,
  1,
  0
];

var found; // Defaults to the value `undefined`
var count = 0;
x.forEach(function(entry) {
  if (found === entry) {
    ++count;
  } else {
    if (count) {
      snippet.log("Found " + count + " " + found);
    }
    found = entry;
    count = 1;
  }
});
if (count) {
  snippet.log("Found " + count + " " + found + "s");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last question: how do you get your output? I've tried putting this into a basic HTML script (see: [my attempt](http://mathematicool.net/test.html)), but this does not give an output. I have also tried adding `document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = "Found " + count + " " + found + "s"` into the function and `<div id="div"></div>` into the HTML, but this has given the wrong output. What am I doing wrong? Also, is this the best way to get the output to be written down?

Comment: @user2910074: With the above, using `console.log`, the output is in the web console (part of your browser's developer tools).

Comment: Okay, well could you please tell me also what the difference between 'console.log()' and 'snippet.log()' is? Thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

First off, I suck at remembering languages, so bear with me...this will be some ugly psudocode...

eval is going to be your friend. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Use a for loop and an array that creates the list of values something like this

```
Array numbers = new Array[10]
for(i = 1, i<10, i++){
     numbers [I]=eval("x"+ i).Value()
}
```

That gets your numbers in a list you can then work with.

You can now do a for loop like this

```
  count = 0
  countsArray[10]
  for(I = 0, I < stuff.size, I++){
      if(stuff[I] = 1)
         count++
      if(stuff[I] = 0){
         countsArray.Add(count);
         count=0;
      }
  }

  //Print your counts or whatever here.
```

Dunno...you can get slick about all that and do it in one loop I think as well.

Comment: there are no types in javascript in this way

Comment: Yea, I know...see my first comment about not remembering languages. The algorithm is what they need, not necessarily the code. The Eval() function is going to get him most of what they need.